# 複数コマンドを同一行で & や && で繋いだときの挙動を知りたい

Tags: bash, shellscript

`;` は command1 が終わってから command2 を実行

```
command1 ; command2
```

`&` を末尾につけたものは command1 の結果を待たずに command2 を実行だと思うのですが

```
command1 &
command2
```

**疑問点:**

`&` や `&&` をコマンドの間に使う例を見かけたのですが、これらはどういう挙動をするのでしょうか。「`bash &`」 で検索してもバックグラウンド実行の記事しか出て来ないので、ご存知の方がいたら教えていただきたいです

```
command1 & command2 
command1 && command2
```

Comment: 質問に対する説明は、スクリプト中のコメントだけで済ませずに本文に抜き出して書いた方が親切かなと思います。

Comment: ちなみに「bash &&」等で検索すれば、恐らく今回知りたいことの半分はヒットします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` は論理積で「左辺のコマンドが正常終了した場合のみ、右辺のコマンドを実行する」です。

よくある例は、`./configure` が成功した時のみ `make` を実行する、など。

```
$ ./configure && make && make install
```

Answer (score 7):

```
command1 & command2
```

のほうは

```
command1 &
command2
```

と同じ挙動になります。
command1がバックグラウンド実行される結果、command1とcommand2が同時に実行されることになります。

Answer (score 1):

## manマニュアルからの引用

`&`と`&&`とについて、[Man page of BASH](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html)からの引用です。
`bash`のmanマニュアルに`&`、`&&`の振る舞いが比較的平易に説明されています。

```
　コマンドが制御演算子 & で終わっている場合、シェルはコマンドをサブシェル内で 
バックグラウンド (background) で実行します。
 シェルはコマンドが終了するのを待たずに、返却ステータス 0 を返します。
　　略
　AND リストと OR リストは、それぞれ制御演算子 && と || で区切られたパイプラインの並びです。
 AND リストと OR リストは左結合で実行されます。
 AND リストは

command1 && command2

という形式であり、 command1 が終了ステータス 0 を返した場合に限り command2 が実行されます。
```

manマニュアルの表示は、以下のようにmanコマンドを実行するか、

```
man bash
```

ネットに接続されている環境では、`man bash`で検索すると大概は最初の方に[Man page of BASH](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html)がヒットします。

## その他

manマニュアルよりも`info`の方が情報量が多いです。

```
info bash
```

私の環境では日本語マニュアルをインストールしていないので、あまり利用したことはありません。